# How do I create multiple Minecraft installations?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to play different mods. I want to play Attack Of B team on one Minecraft, another on a different mod, and a vanilla Minecraft. I don't know if I have to have separate Minecraft files, but I want to do that. Also, I don't know computer stuff very well so try to explain it as well as you can.

Comment: Have you ever used the Technic Launcher? http://www.technicpack.net/download

Comment: I am using MultiMC, you can use it if you need to customize more. If you just want a predefined modpack, then you should give Technic Launcher a try.

Comment: This is exactly what Minecraft profiles are for in the 1.6+ launcher.

Answer (score 3):

### What you are looking for is "Profiles"

1. Open your launcher up and navigate to the "Profile Editor" tab
2. Click on the "New Profile" Option
3. Enter information into the fields

   - Name: Attack of the B-Team
   - Game Directory: C:\Users\< **USER_NAME** >\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\AttackOfBTeam
   - Use version: pick your version this probably contains "forge" in it
   - JVM Arguments: -Xmx2G

---

What did we just do?

We added a new instance of the version of forge in your ".minecraft" folder, now you want to do this again for **Snapshots** and **Recommended**, for snapshots you will check the "Enable experimental development versions" box

Your game directories should be bound to:

- C:\Users\ < **USER_NAME** >\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\Snapshots
- C:\Users\ < **USER_NAME** >\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\Recommended

Respectively,  next your going to want to copy worlds, servers and texturepacks into recommended.  You will want to put your **AotB-Team** in its respective folder aswell.

To play the **current** version of minecraft you will choose: **Recommended**

To play the **latest** version of minecraft you will choose: **Snapshot**

To play **AotB-Team** you will choose: **Attack of the B-Team**